# Passport.js session management without cookie

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, passport.js

I'm pretty new to the node world. I have looked around for this for few days, and I can't find the way to do it with existing npm "official" solutions. If there apologies, I'll hopefully get better in finding the right node resources.

I have implemented a working passport local policy following the various examples available on the internet. It works well

I now want to implement session management, specifically I don't want to use cookies and use `GET`/`POST` parameters instead. The reason behind it is that I'm building this for an API service that might have to work with custom protocols (other than HTTP) where cookies/headers don't exist.

I have seen all sessions support implementation with passport and they all seems to rely on the express/connect session package, that, in turn, seems to support only cookie and have no way to read/write sessions key in `POST`/`GET` parameters.

Before I roll out my own bespoke solution, could you point me to anything already available, if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like that no, there is no way to do that, and the situation is still the one that can be inferred from this answer: [passport.js local strategy- logging in with username, authenticate later requests with token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435075/passport-js-local-strategy-logging-in-with-username-authenticate-later-request?rq=1)` by the passport.js creator himself.

I ended up creating my own. 
For the record the approach I used is to have two passport strategies:

- a local strategy to handle login, and create a jwt token that is sent back to the user.
- a bearer strategy to authenticate follow-up requests, retrieving the token from either `GET` or `POST` parameters, and using the user id stored in the token to query the users database.
  The jwt solution uses node-jwt-simple https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple.

It all works, but I have lost the ability to easily fallback to a cookie based session. Hopefully someone more skilled than me might be able to create a solution to do so, taking advantage of the standard express session nmp

Comment: [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) can create apps that combines bearer strategy with cookie based sessions. It may not be too difficult to implement jwt fallback to cookie sessions.

Comment: yes, it looks like it does, and the principle looks very similar to what I have done. The problem of solution like these is that it forces you to work in a certain framework, and learn that framework, that might be limiting in the future, and requires a lot of time to learn because the docs are pretty sparse. Anyway, thanks for the tip, for a node-angular app it seems an interesting solution

Answer (score 5):

So you can do this.

passport.js uses the npm express-session middleware for the actual session infrastructure.

Since express supports pipelined arbitrary middleware I managed to use the following workaround:

1. In your express setup, add a middleware function just before the express session middleware.
2. In the middleware function, check to see if the session token/id exists on the request (as a header or in the body as required) and if so, read the the session token/id from it.
3. Set the session token/id onto request.cookies object (if you're using cookie-parser) and/or append to the serialised cookies in the headers: request.headers.cookie += ...my new cookie goes here...
4. Make sure you name the cookie after the name you pass into express-session

express-session should now be able to pick it up off the request for resuscitation.

Comment: I tried and can't make it to work. I looked at 'express-session' code to see how they sign sessionID, I used the same way to sign the cookie and set it to req.cookies['connect.sid]. I also tried doing what you said, i.e. concatenating it to req.headers.cookie before the cookie parser middleware. That also didn't work. Even though both methods changed the value in req.cookies object, but didn't change the sessionID verified by logging req.sessionID. So, am I missing something or it doesn't work? I can't make it to work.

Comment: It worked. When I was sending a request, I already had a "connect.sid" with that request, and by concatenating, it had two keys with same name(i.e. "connect.sid"), and after cookie parsing, it was using the first one. This was for maintaining the correct value in req.cookies. And I realised by looking at code of "express-sessions", that for the "express-session" to use correct value of sessionID, we'll have to place that middleware to edit the actual req.headers.cookie, just editing req.cookies after cookie parser won't help because it uses the req.headers itself. Thanks for the solution!